# dynamic configuration of mod_jk

Tags: apache, dynamic, mod-jk

I have configured mod_jk to allow load balance. I want to know if more workers could be dynamically added to workers.properties while apache is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `workers.properties` file is configured in some `.conf` files, to make change to `.conf` file take effect, you need to restart Apache.

See the thread about mod_jk configuration:
http://milestonenext.blogspot.de/2012/09/ssl-offloading-with-modjk-part-1.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.